# How long did the plasma blackouts of Perseverance's signals to MRO and direct-to-Earth last during its seven minutes of terror?

Tags: radio-communication, perseverance, plasma, mars-reconnaissance-orbiter, green-bank-observatory

Congratulations to NASA JPL and the Perseverance Team *and everyone else who participated and contributed in some way!*

Watching the live feed of the [EDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_entry) seven minutes of terror I heard there was a short "plasma blackout" of the radio link to the [MRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Reconnaissance_Orbiter) in Mars orbit which was relaying data to Earth via [DSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Deep_Space_Network). (I also thought I heard a deceleration rate of *10 gees!*)

The plasma is sufficiently dense and conductive that it attenuates the high frequency used between the two spacecraft.

There was a second link from Perseverance direct to Earth, referred to as a "heartbeat" or "tones" which was primarily a carrier whose Doppler shift could be accurately tracked to deceleration profile, along with some minimal health and condition data.

- [Was the Doppler shift of InSight's "tone" measured and plotted somewhere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32335/12102)

This VHF tone is around 400 MHz [and was tracked](https://greenbankobservatory.org/mars-rover-phones-home-green-bank-telescope-answers/) by the [Green Bank Observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Bank_Observatory) earlier. I don't know if it was Green Bank who received it during EDL also or not, but Mars was certainly high in the sky at the time (elev. > 65°), so it seems likely.

**Questions:**

1. Roughly what frequency was used in the link(s) between Perseverance and MRO?
2. Roughly how long was the plasma blackout for both the MRO link and for the VHF tones-to-earth signal? Did the blackout at the lower frequency last longer<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup>since plasma frequency varies with [electron density and temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation#%27Warm%27_electrons).

As an aside, the authoritative-sounding and accepted answer to [Was the time of Schiaparelli's landing chosen specifically so the Giant Meter Wave Radiotelescope could listen?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18707/12102) is "No, because [TGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_Gas_Orbiter) was there to receive and relay it", and in fact this data did turn out to be extremely valuable due to the [unfortunate events](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18870/12102).

Comment: related: [When NASA spacecraft arrive at Mars, is Mars always always above the horizon in the US?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50160/12102) and a related but somewhat moot Mars plasma blackout question: [Will Red Dragon experience a “Communications Blackout” during SRP?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15076/12102)

Comment: It wasn't too long; less than a minute, I think. And yes, I also heard the 10g callout.

Comment: @Phiteros ya I think it was the LRO link that we heard mentioned, but I'm also interested in the VHF to Greenbank signal which I think could have been somewhat longer for reasons discussed in the question.

Comment: I suppose the down vote is because the question is not easy to answer?

Comment: I thought 'tones' were X-band (8 400–8 450 MHz)?

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 the term 'tone' could be used in multiple contexts in spaceflight communications, but I'm asking about the VHF tone discussed in the link in my question, e.g. [The GBT will track the faint communication signal transmitted by Perseverance at a frequency of just over 400 MHz.](https://greenbankobservatory.org/mars-rover-phones-home-green-bank-telescope-answers/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some misunderstandings here (*similar to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52195/40257)*) that make the question(s) a little malformed.

> *Roughly what frequency was used in the link(s) between Perseverance and MRO?*

From [Wagner et al. "Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter maneuver plan for Mars 2020 entry, descent, and landing support and beyond" (2019)](http://hdl.handle.net/2014/49254) (emphasis added):

> Relay telecommunication support in the **UHF frequency range** is provided by the **Electra Proximity Link Payload**.

*The* document for Electra (*especially in the MRO context*) is [Edwards et al. "The Electra Proximity Link Payload for Mars relay telecommunications and navigation" (2003)](http://hdl.handle.net/2014/6577).  It gives a frequency range of **390-450 MHz** in 56 kHz steps or "channels". Mars 2020 makes use of an Electra derivative; [Electra-Lite](https://www.l3harris.com/all-capabilities/mars-electra-lite-uhf-transceiver), which "*maintains the core functionality, performance and reprogrammability of the standard Electra*" ([it's <strike>*lite*-r</strike> lighter on power, mass](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/52210/40257)).

> *There was a second link from Perseverance direct to Earth, referred to as a "heartbeat" or "tones" [...] This **VHF** tone is around [...]*

Presumably this is a simple mistake as ~400 MHz is ***UHF*** in [both ITU & IEEE definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_spectrum#Bands). More importantly; however, is that [the direct-to-Earth (DTE) tones/heartbeats/semaphores/etc. are not UHF, they are X-band](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/52210/40257).

> *Roughly how long was the plasma blackout for both the MRO link and for the VHF tones-to-earth signal? Did the blackout at the lower frequency last longer?*

**The UHF link (MRO, MAVEN) is subject to plasma blackout, the X-band link (DTE "tones") is not.** From [DESCANSO Design and Performance Summary Series Article 14 Mars Science Laboratory Telecommunications System Design, Makovsky et al. (2009)](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/DPSummary/Descanso14_MSL_Telecom.pdf) (*by extension applicable to Mars 2020 & Perseverance*, emphasis added):

> The period of maximum heating is expected to create a plasma envelope sufficient
> to produce a link dropout at UHF relay frequencies (**but not at X-band**), making DTE via a plasma-penetrating frequency highly desirable during this period.

Additionally, the DESCANSO article gives this table of expected link dropouts:

[image: MSL Descanso Drop outs]

So the blackout period was *expected* to be about 25-100 seconds (*for MSL, it could have been less for M2020 due to it's [lower entry speed](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20210024709)*). Looking at the [webcast](https://youtu.be/gm0b_ijaYMQ?t=5662) the blackout appears to last ~50 seconds based on operator callouts.

The lead communicators of the webcast also occasionally mix up the two links (X-band & UHF), though you can note how callouts are still made during the UHF blackout (*because of data from the X-band DTE "tones"*).